# two way data binding not working as expected in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to achieve two way data binding by taking the data from the input and show it in the comment box in realtime.

Here is my HTML Code.

```
            <body>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row row-content">
                        <div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dish">
                            <ul class="media-list">
                                <li class="media">
                                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src="{{dish.image}}" alt="Uthapizza">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                                        <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                                        <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                                    </h2>
                                        <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dish">
                            <h3>Customer Comments
                            <small>Sort by:
                                <input type="text" ng-model="dish.date">
                            </small>
                        </h3>
                            <blockquote ng-repeat="dish in dish.comments | orderBy: dish.date ">
                                <p>{{dish.rating}} stars</p>
                                <p>{{dish.comment}}</p>
                                <small>{{dish.author}} {{dish.date | date}}</small>
                            </blockquote>
                            <blockquote ng-controller="DishCommentController">
                                <p>{{holder.author}}</p>
<!-- achieve data binding here -->
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-horizontal" role="form" name='commentForm' ng-controller="DishCommentController">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2 control-label">Your Name</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your name" ng-model="holder.author">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here is my Javascript code.

```
'use strict';
      angular.module('confusionApp', [])

      .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.tab = 1;
          $scope.filtText = '';
          $scope.showDetails = false;

          var dishes = [{
                  name: 'Uthapizza',
                  image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                  category: 'mains',
                  label: 'Hot',
                  price: '4.99',
                  description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                  comment: ''
              },

              {
                  name: 'Zucchipakoda',
                  image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                  category: 'appetizer',
                  label: '',
                  price: '1.99',
                  description: 'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                  comment: ''
              },

              {
                  name: 'Vadonut',
                  image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                  category: 'appetizer',
                  label: 'New',
                  price: '1.99',
                  description: 'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                  comment: ''
              },

              {
                  name: 'ElaiCheese Cake',
                  image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                  category: 'dessert',
                  label: '',
                  price: '2.99',
                  description: 'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                  comment: ''
              }
          ];

          $scope.dishes = dishes;

          $scope.select = function(setTab) {
              $scope.tab = setTab;

              if (setTab === 2) {
                  $scope.filtText = "appetizer";
              } else if (setTab === 3) {
                  $scope.filtText = "mains";
              } else if (setTab === 4) {
                  $scope.filtText = "dessert";
              } else {
                  $scope.filtText = "";
              }
          };

          $scope.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
              return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
          };

          $scope.toggleDetails = function() {
              $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails;
          };

      }])

      .controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.feedback = {
              mychannel: '',
              firstName: "",
              lastName: "",
              agree: false,
              email: ""
          };

          $scope.channels = [{
              value: 'tel',
              label: 'Tel.'
          }, {
              value: 'Email',
              label: 'Email'
          }];

          $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;
      }])

      .controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.sendFeedback = function() {
              console.log($scope.feedback);

              if ($scope.feedback.agree && ($scope.feedback.mychannel == "")) {
                  $scope.invalidChannelSelection = true;
                  console.log('incorrect');
              } else {
                  $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;
                  $scope.feedback = {
                      mychannel: "",
                      firstName: "",
                      lastName: "",
                      agree: false,
                      email: ""
                  };
                  $scope.feedback.mychannel = "";
                  $scope.feedbackForm.$setPristine();
                  console.log($scope.feedback);
              }
          }
      }])

      .controller('dishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

          var dish = {
              name: 'Uthapizza',
              image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
              category: 'mains',
              label: 'Hot',
              price: '4.99',
              description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
              comments: [

                  {
                      rating: 5,
                      comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                      author: "John Lemon",
                      date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                  }, {
                      rating: 4,
                      comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                      author: "Paul McVites",
                      date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                  }, {
                      rating: 3,
                      comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
                      author: "Michael Jaikishan",
                      date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                  }, {
                      rating: 4,
                      comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                      author: "Ringo Starry",
                      date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                  }, {
                      rating: 5,
                      comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                      author: "25 Cent",
                      date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                  },

              ]
          };

          $scope.dish = dish;
          dish.date = '';

      }])

      .controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

          //Step 1: Create a JavaScript object to hold the comment from the form

          $scope.holder = {
            rating: 5, 
            author: '',
            comment: ''
          };

          $scope.submitComment = function() {

              //Step 2: This is how you record the date
              $scope.date = new Date().toISOString();

              // Step 3: Push your comment into the dish's comment array
              $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.holder);

              //Step 4: reset your form to pristine

              //Step 5: reset your JavaScript object that holds your comment
          }
      }])

  ;
```

I unable to figure it out as to how to make it work.

Comment: Please be a lot more specific about what specific problem and what is or isn't working is as per [ask]. Also scale this down to a [mcve]

Comment: I want the comment to be updated in real time, but it doesn't work

Comment: Be more specific and remove all irrelevant html

Comment: I did remove irrelevant html

Comment: Things like radios , headings, content text don't appear to be relevant to problem

Comment: removed those too.

Comment: New scope will be created when u initialize ng-controller everytime.

Comment: So, how am i supposed to fix this issue  ?

Comment: Y u need these many controllers? Very hard to maintain if u develop like this. Try to do in single controller. Take a look on best practices doc.

Comment: I'll try it in a single controller and let you know, thanks.

Comment: I tried a single controller and it all worked. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was that I was using too many controllers and each of them were creating different scopes. So, I wasn't able to achieve the result I wanted.